# Conditionally add to Map

Tags: flutter, object, dart

I have a Map to which I would like add elements only if they meet a condition.

For example, if for keys `a` and `b`, is there something that works like this?

```
Map myMap = {
  if a is not null "a" : a,
  if b is not null and be is not empty "b": b,
}
```

So `a` and `b` would not be in the map unless the condition is met

For example for react is goes something like this

```
const myMap = {
  ...(a != null && { a: a }),
  ...(b != null && b.length > 0 && { b: b }),
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this in dartpad:

```
void main() {
  for (var a in [null, 15]) {
    for (var b in [null, '', 'hello']) {
      var myMap = {
        if (a != null) 'a': a,
        if (b != null && b.isNotEmpty) 'b': b,
      };

      print('a = $a, b = $b, myMap = $myMap');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do absolutely the same in Dart!

```
return {
   if (true) ...{'key': value},
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Dartpad is very useful

```
   void main() {
    Map<String, String> myMap = new Map();    
    Map<String,String> array = {"a":"apple","b":"g"}; 

    array.forEach((key,value){ 
     value.length> 0 ? myMap.addAll({key: value}): "";
    });
    print(myMap);
}
```

Comment: This is just very bad code. Don't do that